# How Make Request Body for Put Request in Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, spotify

How would I turn this request body below into a put request call with Alamofire?

```
{
  "context_uri": "spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr",
  "offset": {
    "position": 5
  },
  "position_ms": 0
}
```

It currently looks like this,

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "request": [
                "context_uri" : "spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr",
                "offset" : "",
                "position_ms": 0
        ]
    ]
```

But it doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [this](https://developer.spotify.com/console/put-play/) endpoint it would be

```swift
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
    "context_uri": "spotify:album:5ht7ItJgpBH7W6vJ5BqpPr",
    "offset": [
        "position": 5
    ],
    "position_ms": 0
]
```

And make sure to use JSON encoding.